# Excel VSTO - Hide multiple columns lambda function issue - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda, range, vsto, hide

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code below, but no success so far.
My simple task is to hide multiple Excel columns using VSTO / VB.NET.

This works:

```
Dim app As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim act_sheet As Excel.Worksheet = app.ActiveSheet
act_sheet.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
act_sheet.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

This doesn't work:

```
Dim app As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim act_sheet As Excel.Worksheet = app.ActiveSheet
Dim base_hide As New List(Of String)({"A:A", "B:B"})
base_hide.ForEach(Function(x) act_sheet.Range(x).EntireColumn.Hidden = True)
```

I get no errors compiling it, the string address is taken correctly. Any idea?

Thank you,
C

Answer (score 0):

Found what caused the issue. Running a ForEach loop as lambda with Function() would expect to return something. My code inside the function never run. Changing it to Sub() works as expected.

```
base_hide.ForEach(Sub(x) act_sheet.Range(x).EntireColumn.Hidden = True)
```